# NextJS 13 Set responsive option to a Bootstrap DataTable

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-5, next.js13

"I'm displaying in NextJS 13  data in a datatable as shown in the following excerpt from the 'page.tsx' file:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

async function fetchResults()  {
      const resultsResponse = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/single",{
      cache:"default"
      });  
return resultsResponse.json();}

export default async function Page() {
const results = await fetchResults();

return (

<div className="container mt-4">
    <h1 className="text-center text-primary mt-3 mb-3">Championship 2023</h1> 
        <div className="card">
                <div className="card-header text-primary" style= 
                {{background:"Linen"}}>Results Teams</div>
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <div className="table-responsive">                  
                            <table id = '#runners_data' className="table table-hover 
                            table-bordered table-sm display responsive nowrap">
                                <thead>
                                    
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                                                
                                </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>                          
                </div>
          </div>
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
         <script 
   src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossOrigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.9/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
    </div>
 );
}
```

How and where can I set the responsive option of the table to true? How do I use the function described in the documentation:

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( { responsive: true } );?"
```